# scheduling a task in Android

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to develop an app for Android and I want my app
to receive as input the time (year, month, day, hour, minute) and the app 
should put a message on the screen at that time.
Any ideas on how can I schedule a task ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)